# Swift: Play a local video and apply CIFilter in realtime

Tags: swift, cifilter

I'm trying to play a local video and apply a `CIFilter` in realtime with no lag. How can I do that? I already know how to apply a `CIFilter` to a video in `AVPlayer` but the performance it's not as fast as I want.

This is my current code:

```
@objc func exposure(slider: UISlider, event: UIEvent) {
    if let touchEvent = event.allTouches?.first {
        switch touchEvent.phase {
        case .moved:
            player.currentItem?.videoComposition = AVVideoComposition(asset: player.currentItem!.asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { request in
             
                let exposureFilter = CIFilter.exposureAdjust()
                exposureFilter.inputImage = request.sourceImage.clampedToExtent()
                exposureFilter.ev = slider.value
             
                let output = self.exposureFilter.outputImage!.cropped(to: request.sourceImage.extent)

                // Provide the filter output to the composition
                request.finish(with: output, context: nil)
         })
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Can you please describe what kind of filters you are applying? Depending on the filters, the filtering operation itself can be quite expensive, resulting in less FPS during playback.

Comment: Hi Frank! I'm applying basics filters like exposure, contrast, temperature, etc. These filters are applied by moving a slider, that's why I need realtime performance.

Comment: I see. Can you please post some code showing how you apply the filters and how changing a slider changes the filter values? Thanks!

Comment: Done @FrankSchlegel

Comment: @FrankSchlegel how can i solve the problem of less FPS during playback?

Comment: How much less FPS do you get? Some filters are more expensive than others, so you might not be able to achieve 60 FPS on all devices, for instance.

Comment: Sorry about my late response @FrankSchlegel. I don't really know how to see the exact FPS I'm getting, but the lag is noticeable when i use the CIColorCube filter (when I apply a LUT to a video)

Comment: Hmm, that should be relatively cheap. Are you constructing the LUT data only once or with each frame?

Comment: I'm creating the LUT data only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you re-create and re-assign the video composition to the player item *every time* the slider value changes. This is very costly and unnecessary. You can do the following instead:

- Create the filter somewhere *outside* the composition block and keep a reference to it, for instance in a property.
- Also, create the composition only once and let it apply the *referenced* filter (instead of creating a new one with every frame).
- When the slider value changes, only set the corresponding parameter value of the filter. The next time the composition will render a frame, it will automatically use the new parameter value because it uses a reference to the just-changed filter.

Something like this:

```
let exposureFilter = CIFilter.exposureAdjust()

init() {
    // set initial composition
    self.updateComposition()
}

func updateComposition() {
    player.currentItem?.videoComposition = AVVideoComposition(asset: player.currentItem!.asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { request in
        self.exposureFilter.inputImage = request.sourceImage.clampedToExtent()
        let output = self.exposureFilter.outputImage!.cropped(to: request.sourceImage.extent)
        request.finish(with: output, context: nil)
    })
}

@objc func exposureChanged(slider: UISlider) {
    self.exposureFilter.ev = slider.value
    // we need to re-set the composition if the player is paused to cause an update (see remark below)
    if player.rate == 0.0 {
        self.updateComposition()
    }
}
```

(By the way, you can just do `slider.addTarget(self, action:#selector(exposureChanged(slider:)), for: .valueChanged)` to get notified when the slider value changes. No need to evaluate events.)

One final note: There actually is a use case when you want to re-assign the composition, which is when the player is currently paused but you still want to show a preview of the current frame with the filter values change. Please refer to [this technical note from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1966/_index.html) on how to do that.

Comment: This worked really well. I mean, the performance is fast, but not extremely fast. Don't you think I should use Metal achieve that speed?

Comment: That's strange. `exposureAdjust` should definitely be able to filter video frames at a very high frame rate. Are you sure it's the filter's fault? Have you tried doing nothing (just passing the input frames through) in the composition and comparing the performance?

Comment: Yes, it filters the video frames at a very high frame rate (that's why I marked your answer as correct), but I thought Metal could do it even faster. Anyway I'm gonna do it the way you told me, I appreciate your answer a lot! 

But now I'm facing another problem: if I move the slider while AVPlayer is paused I can't see the changes in real time, I see them when I tap play again. Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: Yes, please see the "one final note" in my answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry about my ignorance. I read that technical note but I don't really understand it... Can you please show me how that new code should be integrated to the code in your answer?

Comment: It worked like a charm! You're the best Frank, THANK YOU SO MUCH!